# Include year range in the Google Scholar query

Tags: google-scholar

Can I include the year range search criteria in the query itself?

For example, if I want to search for a few words that an author published on the specific conference, I would form the query this way:

```
some few words author:"An Author" source:"A Venue"
```

However, if I want to constrain the search to only a specific year range, that is done by clicking to the Advanced Search button and entering the range there. As something like:

```
some few words author:"An Author" source:"A Venue" year:2016 year:2017
```

does not work, is there a way to enter the year range within the query itself?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the left "Custom range..." or add to the end of the URL:
&as_ylo=2016&as_yhi=2017
as in:
https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=richard+feynman&as_ylo=2016&as_yhi=2017